# CoreData - Benefits of NSManagedObject Subclass

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to insert into CoreData without creating a subclass of NSManagedObject. but my app crashes with NSManagedObject setValue:forUndefinedKey "name" in Category.

```
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let entitiyDesc = NSEntityDescription()
    entitiyDesc.name = "Category"
    guard let data = model.data else { return }
    for d in data {
        let managedObject = NSManagedObject.init(entity: entitiyDesc, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
        managedObject.setValue(d.name, forKey: "name")
    }
    try! managedObjectContext.save()
```

What are the benefits of subclassing NSManagedObjects

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the way you are using Core Data.  Generally you start wanting to subclass when:

- You want convenience methods on your `NSManagedObject`
- You are using transient values that are not in the model at all
- Want to react to the creation or insertion of an `NSManagedObject`
- Want to present an easier to use object to your UI developers
- Want to avoid using "magic strings" when accessing properties

and I am sure there are more in that list.

You never **need** to subclass an `NSManagedObject` but in many situations it does make your code cleaner and easier to maintain.

A couple of comments on your code:

- `NSEntityDescription` and `NSManagedObject` should not be created that way.  You should be using the convenience method `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(_:)` instead
- Using a forced try like that is very bad for error handling.  You are **FAR** better off using a do/catch so that you can interrogate the error completely.  This is especially important with Core Data that will send you sub errors.
- Accessing the `NSManagedObjectContext` through the `AppDelegate` like that is a poor design (yes I know its in the Apple template).  It is far better to use dependency injection as discussed in the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html) and avoid the tight coupling that is inherent with accessing the `AppDelegate`

Comment: Upvote for the comment about dependency injection. Coupling to your AppDelegate has been rough for me over the years.

Comment: Thank you Marcus for the points. I am honoured to get a reply from you. I am learning core data from cimgf already. I am trying to add support for Core Data in my networking library - http://github.com/Restofire/Restofire. Could you please help me identify the cause of crash also.

Comment: @RahulKatariya What is the crash?  What is the error?  Do you have a link to the question?

Comment: At this point the app crashes - managedObject.setValue(d.name, forKey: "name").

Comment: @RahulKatariya You should open a new question and post the full error.  Just saying "it crashes" does not give anyone sufficient information to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing NSManagedObject honestly makes your life easier as a developer.

- No need to hassle with `setValue:forUndefinedKey`.
- Easy initializer for every entity
- Easier to manage your entities with auto generated models by Xcode

You should check out the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CreatingObjects.html) or [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-subclassing-nsmanagedobject--cms-25116) to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Marcus Zarra's answer is 100% correct, but I would just like to stress that considering the risks of "undefined key" and type-casting errors, and the debugging cost while mentally remembering which entities have which attribute keys, **to subclass or not should not even be a choice**.

Strongly-typing your `NSManagedObject`s (i.e. by subclassing) also opens up a whole lot of compile-time checks and utility, especially in Swift.

If you are new to Core Data let me introduce you to the library I wrote, [CoreStore](https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore), which was heavily designed around Swift's type-safety:

- Generics allow for zero type-casting
- Entity-aware `NSFetchedResultsController`-like observers
- Protocol-based data importing

You also get powerful features such as transactions, progressive migrations, and more. It's like Core Data on training wheels; if there's a bad practice in Core Data, CoreStore will most likely not let you write that code in the first place.

Comment: I do not recommend to people to wrap Core Data in third party libraries.  They are **FAR** better off learning Core Data itself than abstracting away from what is already an abstraction.

Comment: IMO the fastest way to learn a huge framework like CoreData is to absorb best practices from others (including wrapper libs.) Why waste time falling into Core Data pitfalls when others already solved those problems? They can still learn Core Data without sacrificing productivity.

Comment: Core Data is not huge and wrapping it to hide it is backwards.  Plenty of people disagree with me as evidence by all the wrappers that everyone writes but they really are not necessary and tend to hide issues or introduce more issues than they try and solve.